# How to disable height property for table in react virtualised?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, node-modules, react-virtualized

I'm using react-virtualised to render a html table in my react app. The height property on the  element is set as required by default. Now I don't want to set heigth to the table, but I want to set max-height to it. The reason is by setting a fixed height which can display 20 records at a time, if the api returns only 3 records there's a huge whitespace with border left below. I've gone through the docs but couldn't find any fix to it.

```
          <Table
            rowClassName={({ index }) => rowClassName({ index })}
            headerHeight={50}
            height={700}  
            width={1200}
            rowHeight={40}
            rowCount={props.exceldata.length}
            rowGetter={({ index }) => props.exceldata[index]}
          >
            <Column label="email" dataKey="email" width={450} />
            <Column label="JoinDate" dataKey="JoinDate" width={200} />
            <Column label="isVip" dataKey="isVip" width={120} />
            <Column label="onBoarding" dataKey="onBoarding" width={150} />
          </Table>
```

I tried adding "autoHeight" property to the table but I can only see the header of table and the whole body in a small line. Also I followed the height property of  to some file in node modules, added a question mark next to height property to make it optional but the table is not being rendered at all.

Also If I add max-height over the height property it doesn't work. I would be glad if someone can help me find a React-virtualised solution to this or even a CSS fix works too. Someway I can override height property and make the table see only max-height property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured a javascript way to do this. I'm passing an expression to height property to set either the minimum height of 20 rows or the height of no of rows if less than 20.

```
height={Math.min(700, props.exceldata.length * 40 + 50)}
```

'props.exceldata' is the array containing json objects/table rows. 700(px) is the min height to display which can show 20 records at a time. Or if the rows in array is less than 20, I'm calculating height of those rows by multiplying no. of rows with height of each row(40px). And '50' is the header height of table.